# rxjs and subscribe to new values in a collection

Tags: rxjs

How do i subscribe from a source that is constantly changing ?

```
//emit array as a sequence of values
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arraySource = Rx.Observable.from(myArray);
//output: 1,2,3,4,5
const subscribe = arraySource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

myArray.push(10);
myArray.push(11);



I want the output to include 10 and 11 too but the current output only 
shows 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: That's not how Observables work. You can't change the underlying array and expect it to handle these changes. You use `Subject` that might be closer to what you want to do.

Comment: wow martin cool Thanks :).Any example of using a subject to make my code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate your array to go hand in hand with a subject which will represent observable:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
const observable = new Rx.Subject();
observable.next(myArray);

const subscribe = observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

myArray.push(10);
observable.next(myArray);  // after each push reemit the array

myArray.push(11);
observable.next(myArray);
```

Comment: :) Super Cool but i am still scratching my head how does this work esp this line const subscribe = observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val)); How is it printing 10 and 11 seems like magic

Comment: @jhon.smith That console log comes from subscribe. Subject is a special observable which you can make emit a value anytime you want (using next method). We make it emit the array everytime we modify it. To receive a value from an observable we have to call subscribe. The function passed subscribe is executed on each emit. If you subscribe twice you will see two console logs.